# Twofold, consecutive row selecting starting at different rows in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have got the following problem. I have a data.frame with an x and y column representing some points in space:

```
X<-c(18.25743,18.25783,18.25823,18.25850,18.25863,18.25878,
18.25885,18.25912,18.25943,18.25962,18.25978,18.26000,
18.26022,18.26051,18.26070,18.26095,18.26118,18.26140,
18.26189,18.26250,18.26310,18.26390)

Y<-c(44.69561,44.69564,44.69567,44.69567,44.69586,
44.69600,44.69637,44.69671,44.69691,44.69701,44.69720,
44.69740,44.69763,44.69774,44.69787,44.69790,44.69791,
44.69795,44.69812,44.69802,44.69812,44.69834)
        
eDF<-data.frame(X,Y)
```

Now my problem is they are "sorted" wrong for plotting.So what I need is a function to write together the rows of the two points which belong together (in a list of lists):

> 1 and 12 is ID1
>
> 2 and 13 is ID2
>
> 3 and 14 is ID3
>
> ...
>
> 11 and 22 is ID11

Every so created list within the list of lists should have its unique ID (just numerating from 1 to the end). Well because I got this problem in all my data with different length.

It would be great if the starting point of the second consecutive row selecting (the 12) is flexible always taking the first row after half of the data.((rownumber/2)+1) in this example
12.
Well I have tried some things and i think Im on the right way but I cant figure out a solution by myself.

This function is pretty near but i cant manage to make it start at different rows(1 and 12):

```
lapply(2:nrow(eDF), function(x) eDF[(x-1):x,])
```

I also tried to figure it out with seq and it would do what i need if i could make a list of lists by connecting both code samples. Well I also need to change the concrete start and end numbers to a dynamic solution.

```
eDF[(seq(1,to=11,by=1)),]  # selecting rows 1 to 11
eDF[(seq(12,to=nrow(eDF),by=1)),] #selecting rows 12 to end
```

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Reshape your data.frame?

Comment: Well I`m open to every solution which works for different data.frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you needed an ID column inside of the new list but another way would be:

```
#create the IDs
eDF$ID <- rep(1:11,2)
#split the data.frame according to those
mylist <- split(eDF, eDF$ID)
```

Output:

```
mylist
$`1`
          X        Y ID
1  18.25743 44.69561  1
12 18.26000 44.69740  1

$`2`
          X        Y ID
2  18.25783 44.69564  2
13 18.26022 44.69763  2

$`3`
          X        Y ID
3  18.25823 44.69567  3
14 18.26051 44.69774  3

$`4`
         X        Y ID
4  18.2585 44.69567  4
15 18.2607 44.69787  4
#and so on...
```

You could only do `split(eDF, rep(1:11,2)` if you don't need the ID column.

Answer (score 1):

We can modify the OP's `lapply` code

```
lapply(1:11, function(i) eDF[c(i, i+11),])
```